# Converting int to Char not working with int type but does with uint16_t sprintf

Tags: mysql, c, http, char, freertos

I have an ESP8266 connected to wifi and its interfacing with a variety of sensors. I am sending data to a mySQL database. When I send the HTTP post request, the values for one of the sensors gets posted but the other doesn't even though I am basically using the same code. Any help? I'm new to embedded C, and have a feeling I have concatenated my chars incorrectly.

Variables:

values declared globally

```
typechar *URL = "http://localHost/post-sensor-readings.php";
char *postHeader = "api_key";
char *tempEntry = "&temphumSensor=";
char *soilEntry = "&soilmoistSensor=";
char *npkEntry = "&npkSensor=";
char *tempSensor[10];
char *humiditySensor;
char *moistureSensor[4];
```

code that updates mysql database:

```
char output_buffer[MAX_HTTP_OUTPUT_BUFFER] = {0};
        esp_http_client_config_t config = {
            .url = "http://httpbin.org/get", 
        };


esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
        esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_open(client, 0);




char  post_data[151];
        char *post_header ="api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";
         strcpy(post_data, post_header);

         strcat(post_data, tempEntry);
         strcat(post_data, tempSensor);

         strcat(post_data, soilEntry);
         strcat(post_data, moistureSensor);


         esp_http_client_set_url(client, "http://localHost/post-sensor-readings.php");
            esp_http_client_set_method(client, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
            esp_http_client_set_header(client, "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

}
```

Attempt to Update Temperature (Doesn't work)

```
void temperature_task(void *arg)
{
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(dht_init(DHT_GPIO, false));
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    int  temperature[100];
    int humidity;
    while (1)
    {

        if (dht_read_data(DHT_TYPE_DHT22, DHT_GPIO, &humidity, &temperature[0]) == ESP_OK) {
            // e.g. in dht22, 604 = 60.4%, 252 = 25.2 C
            // If you want to print float data, you should run `make menuconfig`
            // to enable full newlib and call dht_read_float_data() here instead
            printf("Humidity: %d Temperature: %d\n", humidity, temperature[0]);
            sprintf(tempSensor, "%d", temperature[0]);
//            fprintf( stderr, "%s", tempSensor);
            //itoa(temperature,tempSensor,10);

        vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Updating Humidity (Does work)

```
void soilHumidity_task(void *arg){
    static const char *TAG = "READING HUMIDITY";
    adc_config_t config1 ={.mode =  0, .clk_div =8};
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(adc_init(&config1));

    uint16_t adc_data[100];
    while (1) {
        if (ESP_OK == adc_read(&adc_data[0])) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ADC read: %d\r\n", adc_data[0]);
            printf("%d", adc_data[0]);

            sprintf(moistureSensor, "%d", adc_data[0]);


            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);


        }
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

[image: mysql database]

Comment: Are you not getting compiler warnings about trying to sprintf() into a "char *[]". I'm surprised any of it works.

Comment: Your tempSensor is defined as an array of char **pointers,** but your code appears to treat it like an array of char. I suspect that's a typo in the definition.

Comment: @AviBerger I had tried  char * tempSensor and it didn’t work even when the variable was int temperature. I’m lost on the structure of chars and char * in c.

Comment: _Caveat:_ I'm not too familiar with FreeRTOS. But, the sensor/ADC tasks update globals that the sending code accesses. There appears to be _no_ synchronization between the tasks, so you have a race condition. The main/sending task may pull a value from a global that is in the process of being updated by a sensor task. What about cache flush/update between tasks/CPUs? Also, I would think that you'd want the sender to have an _atomic_ view of the values (e.g.) The values are taken at the same point in time (vs. being time skewed).

Comment: The update of (e.g.) the temperature `tempSensor` is _not_ atomic because the temp task updates this with `sprintf`. This could cause UB because the `strcpy/strcat` in sender may not have a 0 at the correct place if the sensor task is in the middle of the `sprintf`. The sender could see wild/partial values and/or segfault due to UB. IMO, the temp task should update a _binary_ value (e.g. `int`). The sender task should be doing the `sprintf` calls. Also, `sprintf` is somewhat slow. Doing it in the temp task may mess up the timing of the task.

Comment: I think you want to have the tasks communicate with (e.g.) `stdatomic.h` primitives and/or mutexes (or the FreeRTOS equivalents). Or, have each sensor task queue up the results. I'd recommend a struct (e.g.): `struct sensor_value { int sensor_data; long long timestamp; };`. The timestamp would allow the sender to adjust for time skew for the values between sensors. I'm not sure that having separate tasks for sensor acquisition is better than just _two_ tasks: (1) sender/http (2) task that gets all sensor data. Having (2) would reduce the time skew.

Comment: A pointer points to something else. A char pointer points to a char (or sequence of chars in an array) that you have put somewhere else. `char *pH = "api";` creates a non-modifiable, null terminated array of char in memory and sets pH to point to it. `char *tempSensor[10];` creates 10 pointers that could point to places where you had char arrays of interest, if you had any. `char tempSensor[10];` provides a place where you could put up to 9 chars and a null terminator. Do look at @CraigEstey's comments for larger important design issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. ESP32 IDF function prototype is:

```
bool dht_read_data(uint8_t pin, int16_t *humidity, int16_t *temperature);
```

You pass references to two integers. It is an UB. use the correct type `int16_t`

2. `sprintf` expects reference to the `char` not the reference to `char *`.
3. "%d" only works because of the implicit conversion to `int` in C language when passing parameters to the variadic functions.

Comment: I’m still having trouble understanding why the moisture sensor is working. Does it work because I declared the right types even though I passed the reference to the char* in sprintf? By work I mean update the database.